# BigQuery API - retrieving rows limited

Tags: python-2.7, google-api, google-bigquery, data-warehouse

I'm trying to retrieve the result of query with aggregates, based on the GA sessions and using the BigQuery API in python. And then to push it to my data warehouse.

Issue: I can only retrieve 8333 records of the aforementioned query result.
But there are always 40k+ records any day of the year..

I tried to do 'allowLargeResults': True

I read I should extract all to google cloud first and then retrieve it...

Also read somewhere in Google doc that I might only get the first page?!

Has anybody faced the same situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See section on paging through results in the BigQuery docs https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#paging

Alternately, you can export your table to Google Cloud Storage: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery